# Whenever i am trying to connect my server with mongodb it is showing this error. Whats the problem?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**This is my code. I think everything is good but showing this error
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..**

```
 async function run() {
try {
 await client.connect();
 const collection = client.db("motorcycle").collection("items");
    app.get('/items', async(req, res) =>{
    const query = {};
    const cursor = collection.find(query);
    const items = await cursor.toArray();
    res.send(items);
 })


 } finally {
     await client.close();
   }
 }
 run().catch(console.dir);
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening', port)
}
```

Comment: I see no error message...

Comment: scroll up, above that line: [nodemon] app crashed; you will see full error

Answer (score 0):

1. Your MongoDB Connection URI is invalid
2. On line `3`, where you run `await client.connect()`, you aren't specifying the MongoDB Connection URI. Change your code to be `await client.connect(URI)`, where `URI` is your connection string.